# How do you get the phone number of the current call in progress from Twilio?

Tags: python, twilio

I am trying to allow the current caller to leave a callback number after specifying so with the gather function.

I imagine I need to use

```
calls = client.calls.list(status="in-progress")
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. Is there even a way to get the sid of a current call so I can then get the phone number?

Comment: It would be helpful to have a clearer description of your use case. Who is the user? How will the user "leave a call back number"? I assume the "user" is NOT the "current caller"? What is your Twilio call doing? Etc.

Comment: The caller is given a list of options in a menu. They press 5 to leave a call back number.

Answer (score 2):

The `calls.list()` method returns a list of Call resources which you can iterate through or retrieve by index.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

ACCOUNT_SID = ACxxxxxxxxxx
AUTH_TOKEN = yyyyyyyyyyyyy

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
calls = client.calls.list(status='in-progress')

for call in calls:
    print(call.sid)
first_call = calls[0]
```

The phone numbers related to the call `in-progress` are available via the `to` and `from_` attributes.  For your use case, I suspect the phone number you are looking for would be available here:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

ACCOUNT_SID = ACxxxxxxxxxx
AUTH_TOKEN = yyyyyyyyyyyyy

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
calls = client.calls.list(status='in-progress')

first_call = calls[0]
to_number = first_call.to
from_number = first_call.from_
```

In fact you can see all the attributes available for a call in the Call resource's `__dict__` method.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

ACCOUNT_SID = ACxxxxxxxxxx
AUTH_TOKEN = yyyyyyyyyyyyy

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
calls = client.calls.list(status='in-progress')

first_call = calls[0]
print(first_call.__dict__)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The GATHER verb has an `action` parameter (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action) where you can set an endpoint to receive the results of the caller's response. This call to your endpoint will contain Twilio's standard request parameters (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous-request-parameters).

Your choice would be to save the caller's phone number found in the `From` parameter or issue another GATHER verb to prompt the caller to enter any callback number. Repeat the prior `action` parameter steps.

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but I managed to grab the 'Caller' parameter from the request

Python Flask:

```
request.values.get("Caller", None)
```